# Measure cache access time/cycles for the ARM Cortex-A15

Tags: c++, performance, caching, cpu-cache, cortex-a

So I measured the cycles for accessing the L2 cache of the ARM Cortex-A15.
I did this by allocating one byte and

- invalidate the address
- read the PMCCNTR register
- access the memory location of the allocated byte with ldr
- read the PMCCNTR register again
- subtract first measurement from second

I got about ~240 cycles for cached access and ~350 for uncached access.
I also used ISB, DMB and DSB. Do these Numbers sound accurate to you? I can't seem to find official ressources to compare with. Maybe you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You are not measuring the latency with your approach, you are measuring the overhead.

A standard approach to measure latencies is to use a pointer chasing test, you initialize a chain of pointers so that you get dependent accesses, and you control their placement so that they fit (or not) in caches of specified sizes.  The rest of the procedure is the same except you don't invalidate anything.

Something like this (for illustration, not tested)

```
// prepare a chain of N pointers in a buffer
// Assume unsigned int has the same size as a pointer
unsigned int Buffer[N] ;

// chain them, here in a simple direct fashion.  
// You can also use a randomized sequence if you work in main memory
for (i=1; i<N; i++) { Buffer[i] = (unsigned int) &(Buffer[i-1]) ; }

// close the chain
Buffer[0] = (unsigned int) &(Buffer[N-1]) ;

// measure M accesses
Start =  PMCCNTR() ;
p = &(Buffer[0]) ;
for (i=M; i>0; i--) {
  p = *p;
}
Stop = PMCCNTR();
```

Answer (score 2):

Measuring a single access is subjected to inaccuracy due to measuring overhead and random interferences. You should measure time over a large number of accesses to get an amortized latency that would better reflect what you want. To measure the average access time you also need to make sure these accesses are not run in parallel (that would measure throughput, not latency), so add some false dependency, like adding the content of the previously accessed byte to the next address (after initializing all these bytes to zeros).

Also, you didn't say how you were invalidating the address, but i'm guessing that you also threw it out of the L2, and are actually measuring memory latency only.

Comment: Sorry, should have said it in the first post. I did >10000 iterations and 240/350 are the averages I calculated. I invalidate the address with "MCR p15, 0, %2, c7, c6, 1" (%2=address). And you're right, it invalidates L1&L2 so I measure memory access (350) and L1/L2 access (240, here I don't invalidate).

Comment: @MarkusBraun, are you measuring the time once per iteration, or over all of them together?

Comment: So you're paying the measurement overhead, it's not amortized. This overhead may be significant - i'm not sure if PMCCNTR  is even serializing

Comment: But if I would measure the time only once over 10000 iterations, wouldn't that be less precise? You mean I should: start timer, loop 1..10000, within the loop: invalidate & access, stop timer, and then divide the time by 10000 to get the cycles for a single access? But during this 10000 iterations there could be context switches, interrupts, ... wouldn't that tamper with the end result?

Comment: invalidate all at the beginning, then access them (make sure the access pattern is spread enough to avoid same-cache-line benefit as well as HW prefetching). 10k accesses is short enough to probably not have ctxt switches/interrupts - but usually when benchmarking it's best to disable them if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow. But do you know of an (official) source where those access times are stated? I could really use one for a paper I'm writing.

Comment: I don't think there's something inherent to cortex-A15, it's a generic desing - the memory (and to some extent also the cache) latencies would depend on the actual system configuration you plug it in.